# joomla contact form doesn't give confirmation

Tags: joomla

i'm using Joomla! 1.5.15 (with a custom template) and I've created a contact form.

Unfortunately I can't get it to work; when I fill the form in and click "SEND", nothing happens - the form just gets reloaded (empty) with neither success nor error message.

What can I do to improve on this?

thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the problem remains using one of the default joomla templates. It could be something as simle as you not including the "message" block in your own template